# Large datasets for a project

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Not sure if Stack Overflow is the right site for it, but since there are many DW developers here...

I'm going to build a data  warehouse for a graduation project, and to do so I need a good dataset, and by good I mean bad :) I need a dataset which requires a lot of transformations, is contained in many files (with various or weird formatting if possible). It should also have a lot of columns so a moderately large cube can be built on it. Most of the datasets available on the internet are too simple for this. Can anyone recommend something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use US Census Data? There's lots of different kinds of data available. Maybe focus on a specific state? Your cube could allow roll ups across various political or geographic areas, or by various demographics.

http://www.census.gov/population/www/cen2010/glance/

It doesn't appear that all the data's available yet, so you can always use the 2000 census instead.

Comment: There's a lot of BLS data available as well: http://www.bls.gov/data/  Heck you could try to correlate BLS and Census data :)